# How to deal with duplicate mail in Gnus?

Tags: gnus

I've subscribed to the emacs-orgmode list on my Gmail account.  I've also subscribed Gnus to the list too, which means that I'm getting duplicates.  I prefer to read the mail in Gnus, and have it archived in Gmail, so that I have it even when gmane goes down for some time.

I would like to have an email marked as read in Gmail when I read it in the Gnus org-mode group.
I've set `nnmail-treat-duplicates` to `t`, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: Do you mean that you usually read org-mode messages through Gmane, and want the read marks from that group to carry over to your Gmail mailbox containing the same messages?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Maybe [a mail filtering program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildrop) is right for you?

Comment: Have you looked at [`(gnus) Duplicate Suppression`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Duplicate-Suppression.html)?